# sudo netplan try, error while loading

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, netplan

```
network:   
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens33:
    addresses: [128.100.1.1/8]
    gateway4: 192.168.0.1
    nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8, 192.168.0.1] version: 2
```

root@main:/home/leaf# sudo netplan try

Error while loading /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: what do i do to avoid the error? please help

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml should look like this...

**Note**: Check your static IP and gateway4 addresses.

```
network:   
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      addresses: [128.100.1.1/8]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 192.168.0.1]
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`